# I'm trying to install glove_python using "python setup.py install" or "pip install glove_python", only errors comes to me? What should I do?

Tags: python

```
Collecting glove_python
  Using cached glove_python-0.1.0.tar.gz (263 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\10295\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from glove_python) (1.25.0)
Collecting scipy (from glove_python)
  Obtaining dependency information for scipy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/15/e73734f9170b66c6a84a0bd7e03586e87e77404e2eb8e34749fc49fa43f7/scipy-1.11.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  Using cached scipy-1.11.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (59 kB)
Using cached scipy-1.11.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (44.0 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: glove_python
  Building wheel for glove_python (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [112 lines of output]
      C:\Users\10295\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:745: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.

              By 2023-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\glove
      copying glove\corpus.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\glove
      copying glove\glove.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\glove
      copying glove\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\glove
      running build_ext
      building 'glove.glove_cython' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\glove
      H:\C++\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\10295\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\include -IC:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include -IH:\C++\VC\Tools\MSVC\
14.36.32532\include -IH:\C++\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include -IH:\C++\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared
" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcglove/glove_cython.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\glove/glove_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
      glove_cython.c
      glove/glove_cython.c(886): error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
      glove/glove_cython.c(927): error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
      glove/glove_cython.c(1692): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      glove/glove_cython.c(1701): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      glove/glove_cython.c(2348): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      glove/glove_cython.c(2357): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
      glove/glove_cython.c(14104): error C2105: '++' needs l-value
      glove/glove_cython.c(14106): error C2105: '--' needs l-value
      glove/glove_cython.c(14388): error C2105: '++' needs l-value
      glove/glove_cython.c(14390): error C2105: '--' needs l-value
      glove/glove_cython.c(14625): error C2105: '++' needs l-value
      glove/glove_cython.c(14627): error C2105: '--' needs l-value
      glove/glove_cython.c(15036): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      glove/glove_cython.c(15036): warning C4024: 'PyCode_New': different types for formal and actual parameter 14
      glove/glove_cython.c(15036): warning C4047: 'function': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'PyObject *'
      glove/glove_cython.c(15036): warning C4024: 'PyCode_New': different types for formal and actual parameter 15
      glove/glove_cython.c(15036): error C2198: 'PyCode_New': too few arguments for call
      glove/glove_cython.c(15048): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      glove/glove_cython.c(15048): warning C4024: 'PyCode_New': different types for formal and actual parameter 14
      glove/glove_cython.c(15048): warning C4047: 'function': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'PyObject *'
      glove/glove_cython.c(15048): warning C4024: 'PyCode_New': different types for formal and actual parameter 15
      glove/glove_cython.c(15048): error C2198: 'PyCode_New': too few arguments for call
      glove/glove_cython.c(15114): warning C4996: 'PyEval_InitThreads': deprecated in 3.9
      glove/glove_cython.c(15221): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/object.h(148): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      glove/glove_cython.c(15224): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/object.h(148): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      glove/glove_cython.c(15235): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/object.h(148): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      glove/glove_cython.c(15244): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/object.h(148): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      glove/glove_cython.c(15587): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE': deprecated in 3.3
      glove/glove_cython.c(15603): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE': deprecated in 3.3
      glove/glove_cython.c(16714): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
      glove/glove_cython.c(16753): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16754): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16755): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16767): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16768): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16769): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16770): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16771): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16772): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16815): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16816): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16817): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16818): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16819): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16820): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16842): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16843): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16844): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16845): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16846): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(16847): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\10295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      glove/glove_cython.c(17012): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'H:\\C++\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for glove_python
  Running setup.py clean for glove_python
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      C:\Users\10295\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:745: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.

              By 2023-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help

      error: option --all not recognized
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for glove_python
Failed to build glove_python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glove_python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried "python setup.py install" and "pip install glove_python",only errors come
I tried "pip install mittens" and "from mittens import Glove" and my python-V is 3.7.16(by using a venv).However, I got erro: "ImportError: cannot import name 'Glove' from 'mittens' (E:\anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\mittens_*init*_.py)"

Comment: The pip error says you're using Python 3.11, not 3.7.16

Comment: Other than that, I'd say it just doesn't work at all, and hasn't been updated in years. https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+windows